# Richelieu - product scraper

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, web-scraping, lxml

I wanted to see how would I deal with a large amount of data being scraped and written into a CSV file, so I decided to get the info out of a random website.

First off, I found a way to search for all the products on the website and I figured out that any product will have a <kbd>space</kbd> in its name or description, so I searched for that.

Second, I had to know how many pages there are so I can go through all of them and take some information about every product.

```
from csv import DictWriter, QUOTE_MINIMAL
from lxml import html

import requests

SEARCH_PAGE_URL = "https://www.richelieu.com/us/en/search?s=%20"
DYNAMIC_PRODUCTS_PAGE = "https://www.richelieu.com/us/en/search/?s=%20&imgMode=m&sort=&nbPerPage=48&page={}#results"

HEADERS = {
    "User-Agent": "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
                  "Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36"
}


def get_total_products():
    """Return the total number of products"""

    search_page = requests.get(SEARCH_PAGE_URL, headers=HEADERS).text
    search_page_tree = html.fromstring(search_page)

    return int(search_page_tree.xpath("//div[@class='ts_resultOptions']//p[1]")[0].text.split()[2])


def get_product_url(total_products):
    """Yield the links for products pages"""

    for page_number in range(1, total_products + 1):
        products_url = DYNAMIC_PRODUCTS_PAGE.format(page_number)

        products_page = requests.get(products_url, headers=HEADERS).text
        products_page_tree = html.fromstring(products_page)

        products_links = [a_tag.attrib["href"]
                          for a_tag in products_page_tree.xpath("//*[@id='prodResult']/li//div[@class='imgWrapper']/a")]

        for link in products_links:
            yield link

        break


def check_if_more_products(tree):
    """Check to see if there are more SKU's for the same product"""

    more_prods = [all_prod.attrib['href'] for all_prod in tree.xpath("//td[@class='sku ']/div/a")]

    if not more_prods:
        return False
    return more_prods


def get_product_number(tree):
    return {
        "Product number": tree.xpath("//div[@id='pm2_questions']/div[@class='noProdReadOnly']/span")[0].text
    }


def get_product_name(tree):
    return {
        "Name": tree.xpath("//*[@id='pm2_topInfo']/div/h1/span")[0].text
    }


def get_product_category(tree):
    breadcrumb = tree.xpath("/html/body/div[2]//li//span")
    return {
        "Category": " / ".join([x.text for x in breadcrumb][1:-1])
    }


def get_product_description(tree):
    try:
        description = tree.xpath("//*[@id='pm2_topInfo']/div/p")[0].text
    except IndexError:
        description = ''
    return {
        "Description": description
    }


def get_extra_data(tree):
    data = {}

    keys = [a.text for a in tree.xpath("//div[@class='prodTableContainer']/table/thead/tr/th[position()>1]/a")]
    vals = [td.text for td in tree.xpath("//div[@class='prodTableContainer']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[position()>1]")]

    for key, val in zip(keys, vals):
        data[key] = val

    return data


def create_technical_tables(tree):
    keys = [el.text for el in tree.xpath("//table[@class='table']/tbody/tr/th/span")]
    vals = [el.text.strip() for el in tree.xpath("//table[@class='table']/tbody/tr/td")]

    info_table = get_extra_data(tree)

    data, extra_data = {}, {}

    table_1, table_2 = '', ''

    for key, val in zip(keys, vals):
        if val.startswith("From") and key.lower() == "suggested price":
            continue
        if key.lower() == "product number":
            continue
        if key.lower() == "our divisions":
            continue
        if key.lower() == "material":
            extra_data[key] = val
            continue
        if "color" in key.lower():
            extra_data[key] = val
            continue
        if "finish" in key.lower():
            extra_data[key] = val
            continue

        data[key] = val

    for key, val in info_table.items():
        if 'material' in key.lower():
            extra_data[key] = val
        if 'color' in key.lower():
            extra_data[key] = val

    for key, val in data.items():
        table_1 += "<p><strong>{}:</strong>{}</p>".format(key, val)

    for key, val in extra_data.items():
        table_2 += "<p><strong>{}</strong>{}</p>".format(key, val)

    return table_1, table_2


def first_table(tree):
    return {
        "Technical specifications": create_technical_tables(tree)[0]
    }


def second_table(tree):
    return {
        "Info": create_technical_tables(tree)[1]
    }


def get_catalog_link(tree):
    try:
        catalog_link = tree.xpath("//*[@id='carouselSegment1b']/ul/li[1]/div/a")[0].attrib['href']
    except IndexError:
        catalog_link = ''
    return {
        "Catalog link": catalog_link
    }


def get_line_art_link(tree):
    try:
        line_art = "https://www.richelieu.com{}".format(
            tree.xpath("//*[@id='carouselSegment1b']/ul/li[2]/div/a")[0].attrib['href']
        )
    except IndexError:
        line_art = ''
    return {
        "Line art": line_art
    }


def get_right_part_info(tree):
    data = {}

    extras = [a.text.strip()
              for a in tree.xpath("//div[@id='pm2_blocDroitFixe']/div[@class='feAncetres clearfix']/ul/li/a")]

    for item in extras:
        name, value = item.split(': ')
        data[name] = value

    return data


def get_product_images(tree):
    data = {}

    links = ["https://www.richelieu.com{}".format(a.attrib["href"])
             for a in tree.xpath("//div[@id='rcMediaPlayerCarousel']//li/a")]

    for i, link in enumerate(links, start=1):
        key = 'image_{}'.format(i)
        data[key] = link

    return data


def prepare_product(tree):
    product_number = get_product_number(tree)
    product_name = get_product_name(tree)
    product_category = get_product_category(tree)
    product_description = get_product_description(tree)
    first_table_product = first_table(tree)
    second_table_product = second_table(tree)
    catalog_link = get_catalog_link(tree)
    line_art_link = get_line_art_link(tree)
    right_part_info = get_right_part_info(tree)
    product_images = get_product_images(tree)

    row = [
        product_number,
        product_name,
        product_category,
        product_description,
        first_table_product,
        second_table_product,
        catalog_link,
        line_art_link,
        right_part_info,
        product_images
    ]

    super_row = [], {}
    for d in row:
        for k, v in d.items():
            super_row[k] = v

    return super_row


def main():
    total_products = get_total_products()
    all_fieldnames = set()

    for link in get_product_url(total_products):
        product_page = requests.get(link, headers=HEADERS).text
        product_tree = html.fromstring(product_page)

        more_products = check_if_more_products(product_tree)

        if not more_products:
            row = prepare_product(product_tree)
            fieldnames = row.keys()
            all_fieldnames.update(fieldnames)
        else:
            for product_link in more_products:
                new_page = requests.get(product_link, headers=HEADERS).text
                new_product_tree = html.fromstring(new_page)

                row = prepare_product(new_product_tree)
                fieldnames = row.keys()
                all_fieldnames.update(fieldnames)

    with open('products.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
        writer = DictWriter(f, fieldnames=list(all_fieldnames), delimiter=';', quoting=QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        writer.writeheader()

        for link in get_product_url(total_products):
            product_page = requests.get(link, headers=HEADERS).text
            product_tree = html.fromstring(product_page)

            more_products = check_if_more_products(product_tree)

            if not more_products:
                row = prepare_product(product_tree)
                writer.writerow(row)

            else:
                for product_link in more_products:
                    new_page = requests.get(product_link, headers=HEADERS).text
                    new_product_tree = html.fromstring(new_page)

                    row = prepare_product(new_product_tree)
                    writer.writerow(row)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

#### Performance

Because the data for products from different categories are different - or even for the products in the same category (some of them, not all), I had to first go through all the products and create the header for my CSV file and just after that, get the actual info. Because of this and because there is a huge number of products (40k+), the code is really slow.

For anybody who'll want to test it, I'd recommend throwing a `break` after the loop in the `get_product_url()` method.

#### What I'm looking for:

- Suggestions regarding ways to improve the code performance
- Suggestions about improving my `xpath`s (or maybe `bs4` would help out more)
- I wouldn't like to use Scrapy, although I know it might help (I won't mind a quick intro into how this might be used in my case)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some of the generic things you can apply to immediately boost performance:

- currently, you have `48` results per page (`nbPerPage` parameter in the `DYNAMIC_PRODUCTS_PAGE`). Make it `200` (looks like it is maximum the website allows)
- you don't actually have to know how many results are going to be there. I'd skip the `get_total_products()` step at all and start iterating over the pages. You just need to know when to stop. One of the ways to do that would be to use the fact that the last page would have the `...-23093 of 23093 results` label
- initialize [`requests.Session()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) session instance and re-use to make requests. This would have a positive impact on performance since underlying TCP connection would be re-used for subsequent requests to the same domain

`Scrapy` would absolutely bring it to the next level, not only in terms of speed, but in terms of code modularity and organization - you would have a nice separation of the spider/scraper logic, you would have your extracted products and the location/extraction logic defined in an `Item`, `CSV` exporting part would be in an exporter or a pipeline.

I don't think HTML parsing itself is the main bottleneck here, but as yet another option - what if you try using `beautifulsoup4` on [`PyPy`](https://pypy.org/) interpreter - `BeautifulSoup` is supported, but you would not be able to use `lxml` parser with it (`BeautifulSoup(html_data, 'lxml')` would not work). On the bright side, it would be under `PyPy` and you would be able to take advantage of other `BeautifulSoup` features, like that [`SoupStrainer` class](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-only-part-of-a-document) that would allow you to parse only the relevant part of a page skipping everything else. And, `PyPy` might speed up other parts of the program auto-magically.

Comment: Thanks for the response! When you have a bit of time, would you mind throwing a few lines here of how a Scrapy solution might look like?

Comment: More, any ideas on how I'd be able to avoid parsing twice the same page? ATM, I'm parsing everything once, to get the header of the csv, and again to get the info

Comment: @Cajuu' ah, got it - you have to get all the possible headers first, right? Well, one out-of-the-box option would be to just switch to a different serialization format - like JSON. What if, you would do all the requests once collecting both the possible field names and all the data and only when you have everything, write to CSV..? Thanks.

Comment: that's a good idea. How would that JSON look like?

Comment: @Cajuu' every product JSON object would contain only the available fields for this particular product, something like: `{"name": "Product Name", "type": "...", "finish": "...", ...}` - in other words, this would be "schemaless" design by nature. At the end, your exported JSON file would contain a list of this kind of objects `[ {...}, {...}, {...}, ... ]`. Hope that helps.